# Getting facebook contacts without showing the fb popup

Tags: facebook, dialog, popup, request, contacts

I want to get all my contacts from facebook and show them on my own on my site. I know Facebook provides this javascript:

```
FB.ui({method: 'apprequests',
  message: 'My Great Request'
}, requestCallback);
```

Is it possible to just receive the information from this call and process it myself?

Comment: or maybe I am not using the right call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way with the Facebook API, but this may be interesting for you:

https://github.com/mbrevoort/jquery-facebook-multi-friend-selector

Of course the user has to be logged in, so you can grab the friends. It is also explained in this thread:

[Selecting Facebook friends from a popup and putting them in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9653197/selecting-facebook-friends-from-a-popup-and-putting-them-in-an-array)